# What is the length of a cricket bail?

Tags: cricket, equipment, wicket

What is the length of a cricket Bail?  How many types of Bail are there in cricket?

How many length of Bails in cricket?

Answer (score 4):

As per [Appendix A](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/appendix-a/)

[image]

(considering the above image) the size chart is as below:

```
     Senior               Junior
--------------------------------------
a        3.49 cm     a        3.18 cm
b        5.40 cm     b        4.60 cm
c        2.06 cm     c        1.91 cm
--------------------------------------
Overall  10.95 cm    Overall  9.68 cm
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. but what is senior and junior ?

Comment: Senior cricket is what we see in international/domestic matches. While junior cricket is a school level (which can be national level) and age less than 16.

Comment: but in yahoo feed i show this line (26 inches is the length of a cricket bails ) this is right  ?

Comment: Absolutely WRONG. That must be the size of a [*stump*](http://www.kingsgrovesports.com.au/Resources/Accessories/kookaburra-county-turf-cricket-stumps.jpg) not the [*bail*](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Cricket_bails.jpg)

Comment: thanks for this information. you have any detail about bail ?

Comment: I just gave you the details about *bails*. You may ask another question for stump. But remember to always search before posting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15442/discussion-between-darshan-and-hims056).

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya - What exactly your question is? Are you talking about bails or stumps?

Comment: As mentioned in my question it's about bails. Thanks